# Calculating rate of presses in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game that calculates the rate of presses a user does in a alotted time limit. I was able to create some rate code.

```
 rate++;
 if (rate == reset_the_timer_lim) {
        timer_limit--;
        rate = 0;
        //print(counter_of_presses);
        //okay print the amt of button presses button/rate

        //so we get a number of keypresses in alotted time unit

        //int calc the rate
        for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
        {
            rate_nums[x] = counter_of_presses;
            print(rate_nums.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Here is the button press code

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) 
{
  counter_of_presses++;
  counter_press.text = counter_of_presses.ToString();
}
```

I have a separate counter (rate) that counts up to another number.

So for instance,

If i set reset_the_timer_lim = 25, rate counts up to 25 and resets to zero. It then TAKES the amount of presses (Input.getKey Code (2nd block)) and tries to store them into an array. It subtracts the rate final minus the rate initial.

However, when I run this code, both of the elements in the array are the same. It doesn't wait for rate to reset, and I'm not sure where to go on from here.

EDIT 5/12/18

```
public class press_game : MonoBehaviour {
public int timer_limit = 120;
private int rate;

public GameObject player_heart;
//public GameObject camera_back_up;
public int reset_the_timer_lim;
private int counter_of_presses;
public int amt_of_presses_before_end;
public Text show_time;
public Text counter_press;
public Text get_it_2_here;
public int[] rate_nums;
private float sum, sum2;
public float amt_to_widen_heart, amt_to_widen_cam;

public GameObject a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a, a6a, a7a, a8a, a9a, a10a, a11a, a12a, a13a, a14a, a15a, a16a;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rate_nums = new int[2];
    get_it_2_here.text = amt_of_presses_before_end.ToString ();
    //a1a.SetActive(true);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    sum = sum + amt_to_widen_heart;
    sum2 = sum2 + amt_to_widen_cam;
    rate++;
    if (rate == reset_the_timer_lim) {
        timer_limit--;
        rate = 0;
        //print(counter_of_presses);
        //okay print the amt of button presses button/rate

        //so we get a number of keypresses in alotted time unit

        //int calc the rate
        for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
        {
            rate_nums[x] = counter_of_presses;
            print(rate_nums.ToString());
        }
    }
    //print (timer_limit);
    show_time.text = timer_limit.ToString ();
    //get_it_2_here.text = 

    if (timer_limit < 0) {
        show_time.text = "Out of time!!";
        //counter_of_presses = 0;
        counter_press.text = "OUT OF TIME!";
        if(counter_of_presses < amt_of_presses_before_end){
            print("You have lost the game!");
            //counter_of_presses = 0;
        }
        else{
            print ("You have won this game!");
            //counter_of_presses = 0;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
        counter_of_presses++;
        counter_press.text = counter_of_presses.ToString();
        player_heart.transform.localScale += new Vector3(transform.localScale.x + sum, transform.localScale.y + sum, transform.localScale.z);
        //camera_back_up.transform.localScale += new Vector3(transform.localScale.x + sum2, transform.localScale.y + sum2, transform.localScale.z);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where exactly is the first chunk of code? And what object is counter_press?

Comment: Edited the question. The Input.Getkey is the (bottom code) I was referring too

Comment: counter_press is a textUI in unity. object.text = "insert_message"

Comment: Well of course the values in the array are the same. You set rate_nums[x] = to the same thing twice. Why exactly do you need the array? What should the array look like? And will it need to be dynamic (list a list)

Comment: so the rate resets every time rate is 60. the amt of presses it got too was 5. Then it plugs in 5 into the array. After that the user presses another 5. The total number of presses is 10. It takes the final number presses is 10 - 5 = 5.

Comment: So the array, in that case, should look like [10, 5]? I'm not understanding what you want the first value of the array to be, and what you want the second to be.

Comment: it should look like [5,10]. I created a counter that counts the number of times a user presses. The if(rate == reset_the_timer_lim) is just there to see what value counter_of_presses at that specific time. Also, when it's done calculating the difference, the array needs to reset for another pair of numbers.

Comment: Where are you rate_final and rate_initial (or simillar variables)?

Comment: so in array its [elment[0], element[1]. So when I mean the rate_initial I'm talking about element[0] and vice versa. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I understand that. I mean, you are never showing me where rate initial is. Could you post your whole code? This would also be helpful as you haven't mentioned where the first code block is. In an update function? who knows

Comment: added all code!

Comment: Dont use the for loop. Just set them individually. `rate_nums[0] = counter_of_presses;` and then im still not too sure how you want the second number calculated.

Comment: you did the first part correctly. so after i load the the element[0] with the number, it needs to wait for the reset to load the element[1]

Comment: So like you get 5 for the first run, timer resets the total number is then 10, subtract both and then thats your rate.

Comment: Just a side thing, for the poorly named variables `a1a`, `a2`, etc., why not just use an array and do `GameObject[] a = new GameObject[16];`?

Answer (score 0):

Think about rate_final as the the live number that the computer is actively counting. That's the rate_final. The number picked up by the (if == reset_the_timer_lim) is the rate initial.

```
 //the rate initial
 if (rate == reset_the_timer_lim) {
        timer_limit--;
        rate = 0;
        rate_counter = counter_of_presses;
  }
```

However, if you look at my code and see how it counts no matter what the rate may be, that's the rate final.

```
   //rate final
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
     {
       print("case1");
       counter_of_presses++;
       counter_press.text = counter_of_presses.ToString();
       player_heart.transform.localScale += new Vector3(transform.localScale.x + sum, transform.localScale.y + sum, transform.localScale.z);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written this tiny bit of code for you, its very basic and only counts rate for three seconds after which it starts couting again but it ma give you some ideas

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RateCounter : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]  float timeooutValue = 3;
    [SerializeField] float startTime;
    [SerializeField] int counter;
    [SerializeField] float currentRate;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (Time.time - startTime > timeooutValue)
            {
                startTime = Time.time;
                counter = 0;
                currentRate = 0;
            }
            else

            {
                counter++;
                currentRate=counter/(Time.time-startTime);
            }

        }

    }

}
```